# How do I use the C Preprocessor to generate a variable-sized (operating system-dependent) hexidecimal literal?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Edited: I'm aware that I can't use `sizeof()` in the preprocessor. I'm looking into modifying my code.

I have C code that uses the hexidecimal values (stored inside a variable of type `unsigned int`):

```
    0x0000'0000'0000'0001 (64-bit/8 Byte system, 15 0's)
    0x0000'0001           (32-bit/4 Byte system,  7 0's)
    0x0001                (16-bit/2 Byte system,  3 0's)
    0x01                  (8-bit /1 Byte system,  1 0's)
```

depending on how the operating system decides to represent an `unsigned int`(I'm aware that most OS don't represent them as 64'b values but bear with me). I would like to generate an object-macro that takes one of the four hexidecimal values above, depending on how the OS decides to implement an `unsigned int`.

A simple (dead-reckon) way to do this is to use a series of if-else statements:

```
    #define SYS_UINT_TYPE sizeof(unsigned int)
    #if SYS_UINT_TYPE == 8 
           #define DEFAULT_MASK 0x0000000000000001
    #elif SYS_UINT_TYPE == 4
           #define DEFAULT_MASK 0x00000001
    ...
    #endif
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to use the `##` (C Concatenation Operator) to concatenate the correct number of 0's to generate the correct `DEFAULT_MASK` macro-expaned value. I know that for a `B` Byte system, the number of 0's that needs to be concatenated with the text literal `0x` is `2B-1` but is no such thing as a `For-loop` preprocessor directive.

In effect, this would work to reduce the size of the `#if ... #elif ... #endif` I'd have to type out.

Comment: Declare your literal as an unsigned int and assign it the value of `1` (don't even need `0x` in front of it). Voila! Done. It will be the appropriate size for an unsigned int on any and all platforms you compile it on. Not a single `#if` in sight, either.

Comment: That'll work, Ken. Thanks. 

Is it still in the scope of this question to ask how to (if possible) perform a series of preprocessor concatenations?

Comment: In *the scope of this question*? No. That's a totally separate question unrelated to this one. First search here to find out if it's been previously asked (and search diligently, because I'd suspect it has), and if it hasn't then create a new question and ask there.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Instead of stating **how** you want to accomplish whatever, you should state your actual problem. Let apart that `'` is not allowed in an integer constant, all values above are type `int`. And you should choose one of the two different languages: C or C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

um those are all `0x01` right? they are a literal so they will be int sized if they fit in an int...

when a mask is done the lsb will be lined up with lsb...

convince your self of this with:

`printf("%lld",(long long) 0x01 | (long) 0x01 | (int) 0x01 | (short) 0x01 | (char) 0x01);`

if this lined up with the most significant bit then it would end up being something like:

```
0x01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
           0x 01 00 00 00
           0x 01 00 00 00
              0x 00 01 00
                    0x 01
-------------------------  all of this | or'd together
0x01 00 00 00 01 00 01 01
```

but instead it is just one (`0x01`).

all of this happens through the magic of integer promotion, where the smaller sizes are padded to be the same value in a larger storage size...

thing get messier with signed values and negatives... partially because the integer promotion rules are more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. I think is a case where I over-complicated the solution to a problem (as Ken White pointed out). One of those "duh" moments.